# Оформить как функцию

Tags: pascal, pascalabc.net

Уважаемые знатоки, помогите это оформить как функцию. Заранее благодарю!

```
Program razryad;
var a, s, chislo: integer;
  m: array [1..7] of string = ('Единиц', 'Десятков', 'Сотен', 'Тысяч', 'Десятков тысяч', 'Сотен тысяч', 'Миллионов');
begin
  writeln ('Введите ваше число:');
  read(chislo);
  s := 0;
  while chislo > 0 do
  begin
    s := s + 1;
    a := chislo mod 10;
    writeln(m[s], ': ', a); 
    chislo := chislo div 10;
  end;
end.
```

Comment: Какие конкретно проблемы возникли с выделением кода в функцию?

Comment: @MBo добрый день! не понимаю как именно это сделать. Не могли бы, пожалуйста, помочь? Можете даже без объяснений, сам разберусь с готовым, а то и так вас уже загрузил. Заранее благодарю!)

Comment: Напишите слово function и название, в скобках аргумент chislo, тип результата - string

Comment: @MBo сделал, далее что требуется сделать? Там вроде бы надо "написать" саму функцию и вывести, Я просто сам гуманитарий и прохожу паскаль в "ознакомительном" плане.

Answer (score -1):

Примерно так. Цикл изменил, чтобы ноль обработать

```
function xxx(chislo: integer): string;
var a, s: integer;
m: array [1..7] of string =('Единиц', 'Десятков', 'Сотен', 'Тысяч', 
                            'Десятков тысяч', 'Сотен тысяч', 'Миллионов');
begin
  s := 0;
  repeat
    s := s + 1;
    a := chislo mod 10;
    Result := Result + m[s] + ': ' + IntToStr(a) + ' '; 
    chislo := chislo div 10;
  until chislo = 0;
end;
```